# Retrieve Values From Drop Down Box of Form [Unknown Source]

Tags: excel, vba

The HR Department of my company has a Personnel Action Form in which one must go through the Department/Division drop-down list box [Image 1] and select the appropriate code for one's department. I have been given the task to create Forms for multiple users from different departments. Therefore, I would like to retrieve the values from this drop-down to have them on a separate sheet and not have to scroll every time I need a different one.

[image]

I have tried looking up online for methods (macros, VBA scripts, data validation, etc.) to retrieve these values, but all I've found suggest I have to somehow resort to the source of these values within the form or document. I'm not able to get to the source of the values within the box. I can't find them anywhere within the generic document HR makes available to everyone.

[image]

Does someone know of a VBA script I could use to get these values without needing the source of them? I'm willing to provide a web link to the document capable of being downloaded by any user.

Thanks in advance. I know this is a lot, but I'm super stuck and going through each value to type them out would take me forever.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the dropdown is filled with a named range elsewhere on the sheet. The easiest solution would be to reproduce the named range.

Go to an empty sheet in your excel, and type name of the named range as a formula:

```
=Department_Division
```

Then drag the fill handle down until you get #value entries (meaning end of range). It will print the entire source into the cells for you. Then you can copy the range and paste values if you need to retain the list.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! I don't know why I didn't just think of that. Lifesaver!

Comment: No problem. Sometimes the simplest solutions are the hardest to think of!